# Typescript compiling error: Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Item[]'

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, q

My typescript functions are bellow. The second function didn't show any error message during editing on vscode. However, when I compile it, the second function shows error:

```
error TS2322: Type 'Promise<void>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<Item[]>'.
      Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Item[]'.
```

When I delete `.catch(...)`. The error disappears. Can anyone help me, please?

```
// To retrieve a single item.
// Q is https://github.com/kriskowal/q
function getItem(id: number): Q.Promise<Item> {
    const deferred = Q.defer<Item>();
    // Async process.
    return deferred.promise;
}

// To retrieve a batch of items.
function getItems(ids: number[]): Q.Promise<Item[]> {
   return Q.all(ids.map(id => {
       return getSingleItem(id);
   })).then(results => {
      let items = [];
      results.forEach(result => {
          items = items.concat(result);
      });
      return items;
   }).catch(error => {
       throw error;
   });
}
```

Comment: Well for starters, you're missing a right parenthesis after the `ids.map(id => {...})`

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the typo. I just changed it on StackOverflow.

Comment: It might be useful to also add a declaration of `Q` so that others can repro your experience.  Without a lot of experience with promises, it's unclear which implementation you are using.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a perfect answer. But it works. There are two workarounds. 
1. Return `Q.Promise<any>`, which is not good.
2. Wrap error in a deferred.reject(error) like bellow

```
// To retrieve a batch of items.
function getItems(ids: number[]): Q.Promise<Item[]> {
   const deferred = Q.defer<Item[]>();
   return Q.all(ids.map(id => {
       return getSingleItem(id);
   })).then(results => {
      let items = [];
      results.forEach(result => {
          items = items.concat(result);
      });
      deferred.resolve(items);
   }).catch(error => {
      // Wrapped error in defer.
      deferred.reject(error);
   });
   return deferred.promise;
}
```

Anyway, it's not an ideal solution. For now, it can unblock those who just need a quick solution.